# how to get previous day in UTC format using ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime, utc

How to get previous day on UTC time using ruby?

Currently I'm using `Time.now.utc.iso8601` to get UTC time format in ruby, I need previous day in same UTC format. Can someone help me with sample code to get previous day?

Comment: That depends.  Did you "spring forward" or "fall back" one hour earlier today?

Answer (score 0):

```
> Time.now.utc
=> 2015-03-22 19:00:46 UTC
> Time.now.utc - 86400
=> 2015-03-21 19:00:51 UTC
> (Time.now.utc - 86400).iso8601
=> "2015-03-21T19:00:59Z"
```